# RenderUI issues with userBox

Tags: r, dplyr, navbar, shinydashboard, shinydashboardplus

I am attempting to create a userBox (package: ShinyDashboardPlus) in a RShiny dashboard using a uiOutput in the UI function. My primary issue is that I could like the userBox to update based on what athlete is selected in a selectInput. As a result, I would also like their picture to update.

Here is a brief sample of my data frame:

'''

```
 PlayerName <- c("Alexander Ovechkin", "Sidney Crosby")
 Position <- c("Forward", "Forward")
 ImageURL <- c("https://cms.nhl.bamgrid.com/images/headshots/current/168x168/8471214.jpg", "https://cms.nhl.bamgrid.com/images/headshots/current/168x168/8471675.jpg")

    DF <- data.frame (PlayerName, Position, ImageURL)
```

'''

Below is sample of my code:

UI

'''

```
  ui <-navbarPage(title=title, 

    tabPanel(title = "HOME",icon= icon("Home"),
      fluidPage(
      fluidRow(column(3,
                h4("Filter Data", align = "center"),
                    box(collapsible = FALSE,
                        width= 12,
                        selectInput( "Playernameinput", "Select Player", choices = DF$PlayerName)
),
              column(3, 
                h4("Selected Athlete", align = "center"),
                uiOutput("SelectedAthletePlaceHolder")

 )))
```

'''

Below is the Server:

'''

```
server <- function(session, input, output) {

output$SelectedAthletePlaceHolder <- renderUI({
                                              req(input$Playernameinput)
  
                                              req(PlayerPositionFilter <- DF %>% 
                                                                          filter(`PlayerName` %in% input$Playernameinput),
                                                  PlayerPosition <- PlayerPositionFilter$Position)
                                              
                                              req(PlayerImageFilter <- DF %>%
                                                                       filter(`Playername` %in% input$Playernameinput),
                                                  PlayerImage <- PlayerImageFilter$ImageURL)
                                                
                                              userBox(title = userDescription(title=input$Playernameinput,
                                                                              subtitle = PlayerPosition,
                                                                              type=2, 
                                                                              background = "Red", 
                                                                              image= PlayerImage), 
                                                      width = 12)


 }
```

'''

This userBox so far works as expected with the Player Name and the Position updating in the title based on the input of the `Playernameinput`. However, the Image aspect does not update correctly. I have not noticed an error message, but a small question mark appears rather than the image its self. Note that if I hard code the URL into the image function, this works correctly.

I am sure I am missing a small factor.

Any assistance in this area of general input on my code would be very much appreciated! Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me.

```
PlayerName <- c("Alexander Ovechkin", "Sidney Crosby")
Position <- c("Forward", "Forward")
ImageURL <- c("https://cms.nhl.bamgrid.com/images/headshots/current/168x168/8471214.jpg", "https://cms.nhl.bamgrid.com/images/headshots/current/168x168/8471675.jpg")

DF <- data.frame(PlayerName, Position, ImageURL)

library(shinydashboardPlus)

ui <-navbarPage(title="My Title", 
                
                tabPanel(title = "HOME",icon= icon("Home"),
                         fluidPage(
                           fluidRow(column(3,
                                           h4("Filter Data", align = "center"),
                                           box(collapsible = FALSE,
                                               width= 12,
                                               selectInput( "Playernameinput", "Select Player", choices = DF$PlayerName)
                                           )),
                                           column(4, 
                                                  h4("Selected Athlete", align = "center"),
                                                  uiOutput("SelectedAthlete")
                                           ))
                         )
                )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$SelectedAthlete <- renderUI({
    req(input$Playernameinput)

    df1 <- DF  %>% dplyr::filter(PlayerName %in% input$Playernameinput)
    PlayerPosition <- df1$Position
    PlayerImage <- df1$ImageURL

    userBox(title = userDescription(title=input$Playernameinput,
                                    subtitle = PlayerPosition,
                                    type=2,
                                    # background = "Red",
                                    image= PlayerImage
                                    ),
            status="info",
            width = 12)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: output]